# How can I parse a string representing an array of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I get from an url a result as:

```
[[1509321600000,35166.44],[1509408000000,35224.31],[1509580800000,35234.60]]
```

it is a String, and I want to transform to an array of arrays.

Does a function exist for that? Or do I have to use explode function and create the array manually?

Comment: an array of array sorry

Comment: "Or I must use explode function..." - uhm.... what?

Comment: maybe treat and parse it as json.

Comment: explode is in PHP, sorry, I want to say "split"

Comment: @luk2302 it is not json format

Comment: @luk2302 with replace "[" by "{" ?

Comment: It is valid json. Try this tool to get this verified:http://json-validator.com/

Comment: no, why would you want to replace anything? Check e.g. jsonlint, it is perfectly fine.

Comment: @user1450740 if u see json that doesn't meant it's about curly braces dear.. :)

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried so far or at least explain how the result ist supposed to look like? As was mentioned serveral times, the string you posted looks like a perfectly fine JSON. If parsed with a JSON parser, it would result in an array of arrays of `double`, whereas each inner array would have a size of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, as the string is a valid JSON array declaration, parsing it as JSON would probably be easiest and most maintainable in the future. Using the `google/gson` library the code would look like this:

```
String string = "[[1509321600000,35166.44],[1509408000000,35224.31],[1509580800000,35234.60]]";
String[][] array = new Gson().fromJson(string, String[][].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function provided by default, but you can do the following by using Streams (if your String has exactly that format you specified):

```
String[][] a = 
    Arrays.stream(s.substring(2, s.length()-2).split("\\],\\["))
        .map(sub -> sub.split(","))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Here, you cut off the first and last two brackets (`.substring(2, s.length()-2)`), then split your String (`.split("\\],\\[")`)(which results in an array of Strings of format "asdf,fdsa".

`Array.stream` creates a stream of that, `map` splits those Strings to arrays, and then you can collect them with the `toArray`-method.

Printing this array of arrays leads to:

```
1509321600000   35166.44    
1509408000000   35224.31    
1509580800000   35234.60
```